# How do I make my model to repaint itself when I click the button?

Tags: python, pyside6

The paintEvent method is to display the program when no action is taken. When an action is taken like hitting the start button, I placed anther QPainter object outside of the paintEvent method to redraw the run bulb, but I get an error so I removed the QPainter object.

However, what I want to achieve is:
clicking the start button should light up the run bulb, while clicking the stop button should light up the stop bulb while the run bulb goes off.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QDial
from PySide6.QtCore import QRect, QPoint, QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt, QPainter, QBrush, QColor

class MyButtonWidget(QWidget):
  
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyButtonWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 
            self.setWindowTitle('Demo Panel')
            self.backgroundColor = QColor('black')
 
            self.width = self.size().width()
            self.height = self.size().height()
 
 
            self.str_bttn = QPushButton('start', self)
            self.str_bttn.setGeometry(self.width*0.4, self.height*0.5, 50, 50)
            self.str_bttn.setStyleSheet('border-radius : 25; border : 1px solid black')
            self.stp_bttn = QPushButton('stop', self)
            self.stp_bttn.setGeometry(self.width*0.7, self.height*0.5, 50, 50)
            self.stp_bttn.setStyleSheet('border-radius : 25; border : 1px solid black')
 
            dial_bttn = QDial(self)
            dial_bttn.setGeometry(self.width*0.5, self.height*0.8, 100, 100)
            dial_bttn.setNotchesVisible(True)
            dial_bttn.setWrapping(False)
            dial_bttn.setSliderPosition(1)
            dial_bttn.valueChanged.connect(self.reFresh)
 
 
        def reFresh(self):
            self.update()
 

        def paintEvent(self, e):
            painter = QPainter(self)
 
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(self.backgroundColor)
            rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
            painter.fillRect(rect, brush)
   
            # Define our drawing area
            d_width = self.width
            d_height = self.height
 
            runBulb = painter.drawEllipse(d_width*0.2, d_height*0.1, 50, 50)
            tripBulb = painter.drawEllipse(d_width*0.7, d_height*0.1, 50, 50)
 
 
            if isinstance(self.str_bttn, QPushButton):
                painter.setBrush(QColor('red'))
                runBulb = painter.drawEllipse(d_width*0.2, d_height*0.1, 50, 50)
  
            elif isinstance(self.stp_bttn, QPushButton):
                painter.setBrush(QColor('yellow'))
                tripBulb = painter.drawEllipse(d_width*0.7, d_height*0.1, 50, 50)
 
 
            pen = painter.pen()
            pen.setColor(QColor('red'))
            painter.setPen(pen)
 
            font = painter.font()
            font.setPointSize(15)
            painter.setFont(font)
 
            runText = painter.drawText(d_width*0.21, d_height*0.08, 'Run')
            tripText = painter.drawText(d_width*0.71, d_height*0.08, 'Trip')
 
 
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication([])
     w = MyButtonWidget()
     w.resize(QSize(800, 600))
     w.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How can I work this out?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the following phrase "I am made a qpainter object outside the paintEvent formula and it does not show the qpainter object". It doesn't make a lot of sense ("show the qpainter object?!"), and you *are* creating QPainter in the `paintEvent`.

Comment: I've modified the question. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Sorry but your question is still confusing: 1. which is the "stop bulb"? Are you referring to `stp_bttn` or the circle next to "Trip"? 2. when running your code, the "Run" bulb is red, is that expected or should it be off? 3. what if the start/stop buttons are clicked more than once? Please take your time to review your question and ensure that it is **clear** to anyone. We can't help you if we get misleading references. Also, it seems that those buttons should control "something", meaning that the top "bulbs" should not just react to clicks, but to the actual *state* of that "something".

Comment: When you run the code: stop bulb is labelled 'Trip' while run bulb is labelled 'Run'. There are two buttons - start and stop buttons. When the code is first initiated, both bulbs are supposed to be greyed out (empty). When the start button is clicked, the run bulb should come up filled with red colour while the trip bulb should remain grey. When the stop button is clicked, the run bulb should turn grey while the trip bulb should come up filled with yellow colour. The dial button is meant to be the circuit power(on/off) switch.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem, what I did was to set the run and trip buttons to False and used update() function to call paintEvent. Then I tweaked some part of the code.

class MyButtonWidget(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyButtonWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.setWindowTitle('Demo Panel')

    self.width = self.size().width()
    self.height = self.size().height()

    #Initial state of the buttons
    self.run = False
    self.trip = False
```